# Is it halal to break my fast if I'm a pregnant male?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I have recently become trans while having my baby. Is it haram to break my fast????!?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is a troll question for the following reasons, which muslim in his right mind would name his user 'KingProphetMuslim", the Prophet Muhammad is the final Prophet. Second of all being trans is forbidden in Islam:

Narrated Ibn 'Abbas:
"The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cursed the women who imitate men and the men who imitate women."
-Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2784

Another thing, you're not a man, you were never a man, and you'll never be a man.